# Generating 5 numbers with 1 input before loss function

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying make an ANN model that takes a constant m (will be changed later but now it is just a constant, let's say 0) as an input and generate 5 non-integer numbers (a1,a2..a5) after some layers like relu, linear,relu ... and then these 5 numbers enter to the loss function layer along with an additional 5 numbers (b1,b2..b5) given by hand directly into the same loss function. In the loss function, S=a1xb1+...+a5xb5 will be calculated and the model should use mean square error with this S and S0, which is given by hand again to tune the 5 numbers generated after the NN layers.

For a dummy like me, this looks like a totally different model than the examples online. I'd really appreciate any guidance here like the model I should use, examples etc. I can't even know where to start even though I believe I understand the generic NN examples that one can find online.

Thanks